# tslint one line rule misplaced 'else'

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have such `config` in `tslint.json` for `one line rule`

```
one-line": [true,
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-catch",
      "check-else",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],
```

When I have code lines like that:

```
if(SomethingTrue) { next("a"); }
else { next("b"); }
```

I've got warning:

```
(one-line) file.ts[17, 9]: misplaced 'else'
```

Why that is happens? 
Is it bad practice to have one `line else`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have :

```
else { next("b"); }
```

Else must be one *one line*. So:

```
else { 
    next("b"); 
}
```

> Is it bad practice to have one line else?

Just easier to read. Its a styleguide for consistency.

Comment: Yes I just realized that `"check-else"` rule is responsible for checking that.

Comment: then it is gonna be `1 line if` and `multiple line else` which is a bit wired I think

Comment: add `check-if` as well.

Answer (score 23):

```
if (condition is true) {
  // do something;
}
else {
  // do something else;
}
```

Notice that `else` comes next to `}`

```
if (condition is true) {
  // do something;
} else {
  // do something else;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [tslint docs](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/one-line/) the problem is that when `"check-else"` is specified under `one-line` the else must be on the same line as the closing brace for your if.

So in your case instead of:

```
if(SomethingTrue) { next("a"); }
else { next("b"); }
```

Use this format:

```
if(SomethingTrue) { next("a"); } else { next("b"); }
```

Comment: Thanks for hinting to the rule responsible :)

Answer (score 3):

```
if (condition) {
  // Your Code
} else {
  // Your Code
}
```

End of `If` and start of `else` should be on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your else if or else starts on the same line where you closed previous condition (}).

```
if (some condition) {
        // logic to be executed
    } else if (some additional condition) {
        // logic to be executed
    } else {
        // logic to be executed
    }
```